# Mysql query to Get number of days between first and last transaction in a INNER join query

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables from 3 different databases on which i applied an inner join to get the data. 
Say I have db1.tab1, db2.tab2, db3.tab3. So my query is:

```
select a.tran_cap_dt_tm, b.lang, c.email
from db1.tab1 a
inner join db2.tab2 on a.id = b.id
inner join db3.tab3 on b.id = c.id;
```

which gives me this:

```
tran_captr_dt_tm                lang    email

2019-07-01T10:26:13.000+0800    en_us   test@test.commm
2019-07-10T10:26:13.000+0800    en_us   test@test.commm
2019-07-22T10:26:13.000+0800    en_us   test@test.commm

2019-07-01T10:26:13.000+0800    en_us   tgarden@gmail.com
2019-07-10T10:26:13.000+0800    en_us   tgarden@gmail.com
2019-07-24T10:26:13.000+0800    en_us   tgarden@gmail.com

2019-07-01T10:26:13.000+0800    en_us   jkrl@gmail.com
2019-07-10T10:26:13.000+0800    en_us   jkrl@gmail.com
2019-07-27T10:26:13.000+0800    en_us   jkrl@gmail.com
```

But this not exactly i want. What I need is to calculate the duration (in days) between first transaction and last transaction. Something like this:

```
duration_in_days    lang    email
22                  en_us   test@test.commm
24                  en_us   tgarden@gmail.com
27                  en_us   jkrl@gmail.com
```

I am using mysql 5.7

Comment: **duration_in_days** for `test@test.commm` is **22**.
pro tip: Don't post data as images people will not reply or ignore. Make that as formatted text.

Comment: modified. please help.

Comment: Do you need the difference or max value? If difference then all the output value to be reduced 1 day like `21,23,26`. You can try @mansi query with minor alter if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(MAX(a.tran_captr_dt_tm),INTERVAL 1 DAY),MIN(a.tran_captr_dt_tm)) as duration_in_days, b.lang, c.email
FROM db1.tab1 a
INNER JOIN db2.tab2 on a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN db3.tab3 on b.id = c.id;
GROUP BY c.email
```